# Set onClickListener on GCM Notification

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, google-cloud-messaging, onclicklistener

I use GCM and when notifications comes I want to make some special things. So, I need something like `onClickListener` on the Notification. Any idea ?
Here is my code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.lastlast)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.message))
            .setContentText(resMessage+getString(R.string.interested_int_you))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Comment: There is no onClickListener for the notification . You have to use PendingIntent for that which you are doing already. In your case, whenever the user will click the notification , MainActivity will be launched and if you want to do different thing on MainActivity launch, you can put some values in "intent" and check for those in MainActivity.

Comment: Thanks for explaining

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very much simple like sending data from one activity to other.

You just need to add your required data into intent.putExtra("tag","data") or in bundle.like this.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("notification_tag", notification);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

and fetch data from your defined activity

by

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("notification_tag");
```

Comment: What to do when activity is in foreground ? In my case only one activity in application other are fragments.

Comment: You can send your notification type in  intent.putExtra(), and by judging your notification type you can open your fragment and call method of fragment